# Get Maven profile name or id in java

Tags: java, maven, properties, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I have a java project (no spring) and I'm trying to get the current profile in java, but I can't find how to do it

I tried to use:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
//      ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
//      InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("/config/archicon.properties");
    try {
        prop.load(Archicon.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/archicon.properties"));
    
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("profile.na"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("profile.me"));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this is my pom:

```
<properties>
    <profile.name>${current.profile}</profile.name>
```

and :

```xml
<profile>
    <id>turchia</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <current.profile>-- TURCHIA --</current.profile>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

this is my app.properties:

```
profile.na= ${profile.name}
profile.me= ${current.profile}
```

this is my filter resources:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources-1</id>
            <configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/config</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                        <targetPath>${project.basedir}/target</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources-2</id>
            <configuration>
<!--                <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory> -->
                <webXml>${current.webXml}</webXml>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
<!--                <warSourceExcludes>css/</warSourceExcludes> -->
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${jbossWeb.folder}/${current.jbossWeb}</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but it doesn't work, any other suggests?

Comment: Have you read https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html ?

Comment: @RobertScholte yeah, I already add the filtering

Comment: maven profiles are available at build time, you try to access the profile at runtime - can you describe the "lifecycle" (not the maven one) how build time and runtime of your executable come together here, and what you need the maven profile for at runtime?

Comment: The question which comes into my mind is: Why do you need the profile of the build process in your application?

Comment: @khmarbaise my manager wants I print the name in the main page for each profile except the production one

Comment: Sorry that does not really answer the question. What is the technical need for that? As I wrote why do you need the profile information...apart during the filtering you could set a replacement in your file...

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't know, my manger wants to :(

Comment: @cyberbrain I'm new to this application so I can't be sure how all works and I need it because my manager want to :(

Comment: Maven profiles are meant to handle different build environments usually. A use for different runtimes is bad because this will lead to a situation where you test a different binary than the one you deliver - if you do it wrong. So do it right please ;)

Comment: @cyberbrain I know what you mean but I'm new here and I don't wanna complain, still didn't find a way to read the current profile in maven, do you have any solution for that? please

Comment: I would probably take an approach as you already did, so: what does the filtered properties file contain? (the one that's packaged) The correct names, or still the placeholders?

Comment: contains the placeholder, I will add to my question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you added the resource configuration inside executions of the war plugin.

The filtering can happen in all kinds of build, not just when packaging the war, so I would add the following to the pom. (I just add the outer tags to show where in the hierarchy to place it, it is not a complete pom)

```xml
<project>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have to sections with resources there so only *application.properties* is filtered, but the other resources are copied as well, just as-is.

Comment: I added inside the execution because while I was running it gives me error with: `<resource>
                        <directory>${jbossWeb.folder}/${current.jbossWeb}</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource> `
Than why include than exclude the same file?

Comment: still have the same problem with the other resource if I add yours, there isn't anyway to clean the resource when it start the other one?

Comment: I added the file once with filter on and *include*, and once with filter off and *exclude*. So this file is processed by filter, all the other files in the folder are processed without filter.

what "other resource" are you talking of?